# Google Analytics and direct access

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, visitors

Does Google analytics regards remote access resources as direct access?

For example:
Suppose: mysite.com and anothersite.com
mysite.com has an image found at http://mysite.com/img/vip.jpg
anothersite.com at some page of it like http://anothersite.com/photos.html included vip.jpg in its source in image tag:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/img/vip.jpg" />
```

So does Analytics regard loading this image when a visitor vists http://anothersite.com/photos.html to be a direct access for mysite.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No is the simple answer.

Analytics work with Javascript which is on a (X)HTML page.

An image would not trigger this call as it does not execute the Javascript.

Use AWStats or some similar server based metrics package to see actual server hits/traffic if you need to.

Comment: Oh! How could I forget Javascript! you are right! Thank you!